# In TeXShop, is there a directive to select biber or BibTeX on a per-document basis?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, biber, texshop

As in the title, I'd like to be able to select whether TeXShop uses biber or BibTeX in the document rather than using the command line or changing the default in the TeXShop preferences.

For TeX engines this is easy; i.e. you can put the following somewhere near the top of your TeX file

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
```

to tell TeXShop to compile with pdflatex, regardless of the default in the preferences. Does such a directive exist for bibliography passers? I want to be able to hit <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for this. Latexmk provides the ability to do this, but I want to do compilations manually.

### Final note

The solution involved a shell script. I've made this [available on GitHub](https://github.com/qubyte/BibDirective), so please feel free to use and improve it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I solved this is a mildly hacky way. First of all, I wrote a script called `TeXShopBib.sh` which looks like

```sh
#!/bin/sh

filestem=${1%.*}
bibtype=`head -n20 "${filestem}.tex" | sed -n 's/\%[ ]*![ ]*BIB[ ]*TS-program[ ]*=[ ]*\([a-z]*\)/\1/p'`

if [ -z $bibtype ]; then
    echo "No option detected in TeX file. Defaulting to BibTeX."
    bibtype="bibtex"
else
    echo "Option $bibtype detected in TeX file."
fi

eval $bibtype $filestem
```

and placed it somewhere TeXShop will find it (just `/usr/texbin` for quick testing in my case). Make sure the script's executable bit is set.  If you have saved the script in `/usr/texbin` then you need to issue the command:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/texbin/TeXShopBib.sh
```

Then I simply altered the preference to pick up this script as the BibTeX engine.

[image]

If the TeX file has a line that looks like

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
```

or

```
% !BIB TS-program = bibtex
```

in the first 20 lines then it figures the rest out and works properly with the TeXShop console, in a similar way to how TeXShop handles TeX engines. This script crudely defaults to BibTeX when nothing is detected in the `tex` file, but is no more sophisticated than necessary for my purposes. If there is any interest in this then I can make it more robust.

Comment: I should also note that this solution will work with other editors on both OS X and Linux; it's not actually TeXShop specific.

Comment: Indeed. It seemed simpler than grappling with applescript.

Comment: Incidentally, are there any scripts for other platforms that read the `% !TEX...` line meant for TeXShop?

Comment: TeXWorks can use TeXShop's lines @egreg and I were just discussing this [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2735329#2735329).

Comment: Very nice! I would just replace `#!/bin/sh` by `#!/usr/bin/env sh` for the sake of portability and user-friendlyness.

Comment: +1 for such a useful solution!  As a warning to others: the default-to-BibTeX feature doesn't work. If you don't include one of the selection lines (e.g. `% !BIB TS-program = _____`), then TeXShop pops up an error message claiming that the TexShopBib.sh file *itself* does not exist. @qubyte: Any fix for this?

Comment: It's been some time since I've used TeX, but the last time I looked this script had inspired a feature within the editor. See the 3.21 release notes here (also for usage): http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/version.html

Comment: It would be better not to use `/usr/texbin` which puts the script in TeX Live's main installation tree....

Answer (score 20):

Beginning with version 3.21, this feature is provided (by this very request!).

From the [release notes](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/version.html):

> The next feature was requested by Alan Munn about a year ago.
>   Apologies for the delay. In the meantime, Mark Everitt wrote an
>   ingenious script to provide this feature. The feature provided by that
>   script is now built into TeXShop.
>
> The command BibTeX in the TeXShop typeset menu runs BibTeX; notice
>   that this command has a keyboard shortcut. In Japan, a different
>   program is used instead, so Yusuke Terada provided an item in TeXShop
>   Preferences under the Engine tab to select the program to be run when
>   this menu item is selected. Examples are `bibtex`, `biber`, `pbibtex`, etc.
>   The Preferences item can also be used to add flags to the command.
>
> In TeXShop 3.21, the BibTeX engine can be selected on a file-by-file
>   basis using the syntax
>
> ```
> % !BIB TS-program =
> ```
>
> The alternate syntax
>
> ```
> % !BIB program =
> ```
>
> will also be accepted. The item after the equal sign gives the name of
>   the program (for instance `biber`) and any required flags. This line
>   should be written within the first twenty lines of a source file.
>
> The `% !BIB TS-program =` line takes precedence. If it is absent, the
>   Preference item determines which command is run.

So, all you need to do is update your copy of TeXShop (it should have asked you to do so).

Comment: Awesome! Can you cite this or point to the documentation for more information? Thanks!

Comment: @jvriesem I'm not sure how much more official you can get than the release notes, which are linked :)

Comment: Wow, my bad. I totally missed the link. I thought that was all your own writing. Thanks, and sorry for causing trouble! :-)

Comment: @jvriesem Not at all! The links can be hard to spot :)

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately no.  This would be a very useful thing to have, but it doesn't exist at the moment. There's been some discussion of it on the TeX on MacOS mailing list, but nothing came of it on the development side.

Here's a hacky kind of workaround:

- Make a `biber` engine
- At the top of your file put:

```
    %# !TEX TS-program = biber
    % !TEX TS-program = pdflatex (or whatever regular engine the file uses)
```

When you want run `biber` on the file, remove the `#` from the first line and hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>; since the `biber` engine is the first line, it will be run first.

This isn't as convenient as having the engine run automatically with <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, but it helps a bit.

Comment: Aye, that is unfortunate. Not really digging the engine option though, since it means working with a split panel and editing. Maybe it's possible to write a script that looks at the first 20 lines for something like `% !BIB TS-program = ...` and runs `bibtex` or `biber` based upon the extracted argument. Wrapping it in an applescript would allow it to be added to the TeXShop menus and a hotkey combination assigned...

Comment: I'll think about that.