# Bypass % !TEX TS-program =

Tags: compiling, editors, texshop, magic-comment

Some LaTeX editors (TeXShop and TeXworks, for instance) allow a special comment line to define a default engine to use with a current document, like this :

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
```

It's really useful when working on the main document but question comes when I need to call other commands (Biber, MakeIndex, etc.).

Concrete situation : I typeset a pdfLaTeX document, but I sometimes need to call Biber, MakeIndex, etc. If a `% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex` comment is present, compiling will run pdfLaTeX engine, even if I asked for Biber or MakeIndex. I have to remove temporarily this special comment to use another engine.

Is it a way to temporarily bypass that special command without removing it each time I want to use Biber or MakeIndex on that document ? In other words, how could I keep the comfort of the `% !TEX TS-program =...` system while being able to sometimes run other commands ?

I guess LaTeXmk (or a makefile) is a solution, but I would like to know if other solutions are possible.

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Which editor and version are you using? In TeXworks, the 'magic comment' only sets the default to run. You can happily change the program to be run after loading a file.

Comment: Close, or possibly a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38348/9043. This may even answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, this line in TeXworks selects the specified engine in the dropdown menu, but I'm free to change it if needed. Unfortunately, this is not the case with TeXShop.

Comment: Perhaps delegating the decisions to `latexmk`would solve your problem?

Comment: With TeXShop you simply choose the program you need from the dropdown menu (BibTeX or MakeIndex). But it seems not to be working with Biber.

Comment: Yes, BibTeX or makeindex built-in engines are working, but custom engines are not (I have to use custom engines for lilypond-book, for instance). I'll try to find my way with latexmk. Thanks to all

Answer (score 3):

Which editor and version are you using? In TeXworks, the 'magic comment' only sets the default to run. You can happily change the program to be run after loading a file.