# Adding a date to disambiguate books with same title in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am working on my PhD thesis and am using `biblatex`. Now I have several books by the same author with exactly the same title (but different publication years). When I cite these works, there is no way for the reader to know to which work I am referring.

I realise that I could edit their `shorttitle` fields to include the date, but then the date gets italicised together with the title. I could then de-italicise it, etc. etc. But I was hoping that there was a simpler/smarter/more elegant solution.

Attached is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[
    style=authortitle,
    hyperref,
    useprefix=false,
    maxnames=2,
    firstinits=true,
    sortcites=true,
    uniquename=init,
    abbreviate=true
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{tom1,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {This is a very long title that I definitely do not want in a footnote},
  shorttitle = {A better title},
}
@book{tom2,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {1999},
  title = {This is a very long title that I definitely do not want in a footnote},
  shorttitle = {A better title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\footnote{\Cite{tom1}, \Cite{tom2}.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55841/biblatex-determine-unique-titles/55935). This has been implemented in the latest biblatex/biber betas

Answer (score 12):

Two bibliography entries with the same author and *title* are rather uncommon, and this seems to be the reason that the `autortitle` style family is (to the best of my knowledge) missing an "extratitle" feature similar to `authoryear`'s `extrayear` field. While it should be possible to add such a feature, this is above my abilities. I *do* have a suggestion that at least does away with manually adding tailored `shorttitle` fields to the bibliography:

- Declare a new bibliography category "ambigtitle" and add the respective entries to this category in your main document;
- Define a bibmacro `dateifambigtitle` that will print the contents of the date field for entries belonging to the "ambigtitle" category;
- Add the above bibmacro to the format definition of the `citetitle` field.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{ambigtitle}
\addtocategory{ambigtitle}{A01,A02}

\newbibmacro*{dateifambigtitle}{%
  \ifcategory{ambigtitle}{%
    \addspace
    \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
  }{%
  }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}\usebibmacro{dateifambigtitle}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
    [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
    {citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}\usebibmacro{dateifambigtitle}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{A02,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \parencite{A01}.

Some text \parencite{A02}.

Some text \parencite{C03}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) [Plagiarism is the sincerest form of flattery?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233141/)

Answer (score 8):

Citation labels in the author-title styles are formed by the `labelname` and `labeltitle` fields. The `namehash` field uniquely identifies the name list in `labelname`.

Using the `\AtDataInput` hook you can count the number of entries per `namehash`-`labeltitle` value. Years can then be added to ambiguous citation labels in the `cite:title` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\AtDataInput{%
  \iftoggle{blx@skiplab}{}
  {\csnumgdef{cbx@\strfield{namehash}@\strfield{labeltitle}}
    {\csuse{cbx@\strfield{namehash}@\strfield{labeltitle}}+1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
    \ifnumgreater{\csuse{cbx@\strfield{namehash}@\strfield{labeltitle}}}{1}
      {\addspace\printfield[parens]{year}}
      {}}}

\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key1,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Original title},
  shorttitle = {Title}}
@book{key2,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {1999},
  title = {Title}}
@book{key3,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B.},
  year = {1998},
  title = {Book title}}
@book{key4,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
  year = {1998},
  title = {Book title}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{key1,key2,key3,key4}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

This approach should be general enough for each of the `authortitle` variants. It also works with `biber` as the backend and various option settings related to `minnames`/`maxnames` and `labelname` disambiguation (`uniquename`, `uniquelist`).

Refinements can be made to perform disambiguation independently between reference sections. The `\AtDataInput` hook executes its code for every entry in the `bbl` auxiliary file(s). So disambiguation doesn't discount entries filtered out of the bibliography. Years could be added selectively, but this depends on the filter.

Comment: This seems great, but I cannot figure out how to use biber with TeXShop on my mac. I'm getting the feeling that that is going to be a whole new issue and question... Oh my.

Comment: @TomdeBruin `biber` isn't really needed for the solution. I've made an edit to give a "more minimal" example. The `uniquename` setting in your MWE does need `biber` as the backend. I'm not familiar with TeXShop, but you might find [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38348/4483) helpful.

Comment: I tried this solution because I have the same problem (citing different copies of the same book, since they contain different marginalia left by readers), so I tried the above solution by changing `year` to `addendum` (the field in which I have the note on the call number of the copy in question), and compiled with `[notes,short]{biblatex-chicago}` but nothing happened. Is this expected? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is not a fully automatic solution: it does require you to enter an extra field.

Redefine `cite:title` as follows in the preamble:

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
\iffieldundef{usera}
  {}
  {\printtext{\addspace\mkbibparens{\printfield{usera}}}}}}
```

Now include a `usera` field with the year you want to be used:

```
@book{tom1,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {This is a very long title that I definitely do not want in a footnote},
  shorttitle = {A better title},
  usera = {2001},
}
@book{tom2,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {1999},
  title = {This is a very long title that I definitely do not want in a footnote},
  shorttitle = {A better title},
  usera = {1999},
}
```

That then produces Author, *A better title* (2001) and Author, *A better title* (1999). The additional year is added only if a `usera` field is present. A bit hacky, but less hacky than actually adding it in the shorttitle field.