# biblatex: determine unique titles

Tags: biblatex

I'm currently working on a `biblatex` style with support for movies, tv series and tv shows. A typical entry for a tv show would look something like this:

```
@movie{Newton:2012a,
Date = {2012-05-12},
Entrysubtype = {tv},
Organization = {ORF eins},
Title = {Newton}}
```

`entrysubtype = tv` is used to mark the entry as a tv show. There's no author or any kind of creator, since tv shows don't have directors in the traditional sense, `organization` is used for the tv station, `date` for the air date. An in-text citation would look like this: *Newton* (ORF eins, May 12 2012). A repeated citation wouldn't show station and date, just *Newton*.

I have all of this working, there's just one problem: When I have to quote different installments of the same show, I want the date printed for repeated citations to disambiguate the different citations. So a second quotation of the above entry would like look this I another episode of *Newton* was quoted: *Newton* (May 12 2012).

To do this I somehow need to determine whether a title is unique, and AFAICS `biblatex` doesn't offer any tools for this. I thought about working with some kind of dummy author, but I couldn't really figure out how to do this sensibly.

So the question is: How can I tell whether a title is unique.

(If needed, I will provide more code, but I think the general idea should be clear).

Comment: A [similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54080/4483) was asked recently. I suspect only biber can provide a fully automatic solution for disambiguating `labeltitle`. It might be worth posting a feature request at [github](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try the betas of biblatex 2.0 and biber 1.0 which just been updated. There is now an option `labeltitle` which enables the `extratitle` field. This works like `extrayear` but tracks repeated labelname/labeltitle. For your situation, you could do something like:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{extratitle}{#1}{#1\space\mkbibparens{\printdate}}}
```

See the updated biblatex doc. Also, `labeltitle` is now customisable, like `labelyear`

Comment: Just tried it, works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something which can only be described as ugly hack, but which actually seems to work.

First I check whether `author` is undefined; if it is, I copy `title` to `author` and then do a `\ifsingletitle` test which checks whether there is more than one title from a certain author. Since the title of the show then functions as author, `\ifsingletitle` seems to do the job.

Here's the code in principle:

```
\ifciteseen % check whether it's a repeated citation
{\ifnameundef{author} % make sure that there is no author
{\savefield*{title}{\titlecheck}% copy the title to a new macro
\restorename{author}{\titlecheck}% copy the macro to author
\ifsingletitle % check whether author/title is unique
{<code for normal repeated citiations>}
{<code for citations which need to disambiguate>}
}
{…}
}
{…}
```

It isn't nice, but I don't see any essential problems.

**UPDATE:** Actually, this doesn't work. Seems like I can't copy the content of a field to a name list.

**UPDATE 2:** See plk's answer which actually works.

Comment: I am looking into adding extratitle and a configurable labeltitle to biblatex 2.0/biber 1.0 to deal with this. I'll let you know when you can test it.