# How to use BibTex with TexWorks?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texworks

I am trying to learn how to use bibtex. I found this [article](http://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/BIBTEX.HTM) and created two files:

```
% Untitled.tex 
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\title{BibTeX in action}
\author{Martin J. Osborne}
\date{2008-1-13}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This document illustrates the use of BibTeX\@.  You may want to refer to
\cite{ahu61} or \cite{ab94} or \cite{m85}.  Or you may want to cite a
specific page in a reference, like this: see \citet[p.~199]{m85}.  Or
perhaps you want to cite more than one paper by Maskin: \cite{m85, m99}.
Or you want to make a parenthetical reference to one or more articles, in
which case the \verb+\citealt+ in the \texttt{te.bst} bibliography style
omits the parentheses around the year (\citealt{ahu61}).

\bibliographystyle{te}

\bibliography{bibl}

\end{document}

% bibl.bib
@article{ahu61,
       author={Arrow, Kenneth J. and Leonid Hurwicz and Hirofumi Uzawa},
       title={Constraint qualifications in maximization problems},
       journal={Naval Research Logistics Quarterly},
       volume={8},
       year = 1961,
       pages = {175-191}
     }

@book{ab94,
       author = {Charalambos D. Aliprantis and Kim C. Border},
       year = {1994},
       title = {Infinite Dimensional Analysis},
       publisher = {Springer},
       address = {Berlin}
     }

@incollection{m85,
       author={Maskin, Eric S.},
       year={1985},
       title={The theory of implementation in {N}ash equilibrium: a survey},
       booktitle={Social Goals and Social Organization},
       editor={Leonid Hurwicz and David Schmeidler and Hugo Sonnenschein},
       pages={173-204},
       publisher={Cambridge University Press},
       addess={Cambridge}
     }
```

Now the question arises **what should I do with them?** 
I didn't find any manual for BibTex with TexWorks.

I compiling `Untitled.tex` into pdfLaTeX and see `?` instead of citations.
I compiling `bibl.bib` into BibTeX and see error

```
I couldn't open file name `bibl.aux'.
```

Comment: Are you running BibTeX on the `.tex` file or the `.bib` one. You should _not_ be doing latter.

Comment: You should also take a look at the modern package [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) in conjunction with the bibliography processor biber. This gives you full utf8 support.

Comment: @Johannes_B, do I have biblatex in texworks? I see only bibtex compilation.

Comment: Biblatex is a package, see the link above. Biber is the modern BibTeX equivalent, but you have to add it manually. See [add biber to Texworks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63308/dummies-guide-to-biber) as a starting point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to Joseph Wright I made it work this way:

1. Compile with pdfLaTeX to get know which pieces you cite and store it in `.aux` file.
2. Compile with BibTeX to create the `.bbl` file (which contains the formatted
   references) from information stored in the `.aux` and `.bib` files.
3. Compile with pdfLaTex to incorporate the `.bbl` file in the typeset document (to include references list in the document).
4. Compile with pdfLaTex to rid of `?` marks and get citations in your text.

Comment: The `bib` file is your database, it is not generated by BibTeX. BibTeX generates the bbl, which is read by LaTeX.

Comment: What do you mean by store it in the `.aux` file?

Comment: yes. could you explain more please. it looks like the TexWorks does not have a solution in the GUI ?

Comment: Great background info can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much to share this, I am searching on the net for how many days just to get this work.

Maybe some others will meet this problem as well, if this way mentioned above won't work just try this:

1. Compile with pdfLaTeX
2. Compile with biber
3. Compile with pdfLaTeX
   if necessary
4. Compile with pdfLaTeX again

Which way you have to use depends on the '\usepackage' instructions on the beginning of the .tex file.

If you work on a template for example for your bachelor or master thesis, I'm pretty sure you will meet this problem as well

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure this really answers the question.