# Getting BibTex to work in the first place

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I've been writing my thesis for a month now, and haven't gotten any further than fighting with bibliography-related issues. I've boiled down all the problems I'm having into something very simple with BibTex.

It seems I can't get BibTex to work at all. To test, I've done a very basic LaTeX document, a very basic bibliography file. Please find attached screenshots of them.

I'm using TeXworks (what else is there for Mac?). In the screenshots you can see that the PDF I get is unable to connect my citations from the .tex file to the .bib file. Why is this?

[image: .bib]
[image: .tex]
[image: Compiled document]

Comment: Are there any (error) messages from BiBTeX? Perhaps a `.log`-file is useful here, your setup here should work as far as I can see. Also plain text is preferred for a minimal working example, as we now have to type out your example instead of copy-paste it.

Comment: You need to compile your document more than once. Compile in this order: ``pdfLaTeX``, ``BibTeX``, ``pdfLaTeX``, ``pdfLaTeX``. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147515/how-to-use-bibtex-with-texworks

Comment: While the linked answer shows TeXworks, it's equally applicable to TeXShop.

Comment: There of course also is the go-to [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).

Comment: Thanks guys. @Sverre, when you say "Compile in this order: pdfLaTeX, BibTeX, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX" - what do you mean? All I have in TeXworks is the compile button (green 'play' button as seen in screenshot above), with the possibility to choose pdfLaTeX or something else. [at]hugovdberg, thanks for the tip - I'll use plaintext next time!

Comment: @abrotherus Yes, so first compile - by clicking the compile button - with ``pdfLaTeX``, then compile again with ``BibTeX``, etc.

Comment: @Sverre Cheers, now I finally understand what that sentence means! This whole LaTeX-world isn't too easy to pick up in the beginning...