# Trying to use BibTeX in Texworks but the reference is empty

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, texworks

I'm Trying to use BibTeX in Texworks. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\title{Weekly Progress}
\author{author}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{arcs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
blablabla
\end{abstract}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}
```

and I create a file reference.bib:

```
@inproceedings{zhang2019gradient,
  title={Why Gradient Clipping Accelerates Training: A Theoretical Justification for Adaptivity},
  author={Zhang, Jingzhao and He, Tianxing and Sra, Suvrit and Jadbabaie, Ali},
  booktitle={International Conference on Learning Representations},
  year={2019}
}
```

For convenience I temporarily put both files at desktop.
I follow the instruction in [How to use BibTex with TexWorks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147515/how-to-use-bibtex-with-texworks) but now the reference part is empty.

Remark:
1. I run pdflatex+bibtex+pdflatex*2 all in the main file.

2. My bbl file does not contain the reference I want.
3. I don't have a blg file.

Question: Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is there any clue that bibtex is run at all? Can you run bibtex from the command line?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example document should actually not produce any bibliography since nothing is cited in it. If you add ``\cite{zhang2019gradient}`` somewhere within the document, does the bibliography show up?

Comment: @Vincent Thanks very much for your comment! The problem is solved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the document's actual issue (a lack of `\cite` commands) was identified in the comments.