# Why Overleaf generates the bibliography while some text editors fail to generate it in beamer and using BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, overleaf

Examined with three different editors: `TexStudio`, `TexWorks`, and `Texmaker`, the beamer as will follow, does *not* generate the bibliography on the *References* frame. However, compiling the same document in the `Overleaf` website, *works fine* and generates the bibliography.

The problems regarding `BibLaTeX` and `BibTeX` with `beamer`, have been addressed perfectly in many online forums, however, this particular one has not been addressed. How could I make any of those editors compile the same code as `Overleaf` does?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} 
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667} 
\definecolor{UBCgrey}{rgb}{0.3686, 0.5255, 0.6235} 
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=UBCblue} 
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=UBCblue} 
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=UBCgrey,fg=white}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} %math
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm, float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\small}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setbeamercolor{framesource}{fg=gray}
\setbeamerfont{framesource}{size=\tiny}
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\begin{textblock*}{4cm}(8.7cm,8.6cm)
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=0.5cm,right]{framesource}
            \usebeamerfont{framesource}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesource} Source: {#1}
        \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{textblock*}}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\small}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} 
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
\addbibresource{Innovation.bib}

\title[Some Wonderful Discovery]{History of This Wonderful Discovery}
\subtitle{}
\author[SomeOne Someonian] {SomeOne Someonian}
\institute[] 
{
    Some Great School\\
    Some Cool City, postalCode, TheNorth
}

\date[WhatAnEvent] 
{WhatAnEvent- Life Is Beautiful, September 2020}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Outline}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section[intro]{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Brief History}
    \frametitle{Brief History \footnotemark[1]}
    \footnotetext[1]{\footcite{bertsimas2004robust}}
\end{frame}

    
\begin{frame} [allowframebreaks]   
    \begin{center}
        \Huge Thank You!\\ \vspace{0.5in}
        \small \textit{I hope you enjoyed the presentation.}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
    \frametitle{References}
    %\nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The content of the `Innavation.bib` file:

```
@article{bertsimas2004robust,
    title={Robust linear optimization under general norms},
    author={Bertsimas, Dimitris and Pachamanova, Dessislava and Sim, Melvyn},
    journal={Operations Research Letters},
    volume={32},
    number={6},
    pages={510--516},
    year={2004},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Comment: Overleaf uses `latexmk`, which automatically executes bibtex or biber: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F If you're not using latexmk, you will need to run `bibtex` or `biber` separately in TeXworks/TeXstudio/etc, and then run `pdflatex` again: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147521/226

Comment: @imnother running `biber` separately in TexWorks, gives the following error: `INFO - `This is Biber 2.14` , 
`INFO - Logfile is 'InnovationHistory.blg'` , 
`ERROR - Cannot find 'InnovationHistory.bcf'!INFO - ERRORS: 1`. Also, TexStudio has a `latexmk` option to compile a file, which did not work for me, and renders this error: `Could not start Recompile Bibliography: Latemk: latexmk.exe -pdf - silent=1 "InnovationHistory"."`..

Comment: @imnohere Well, the issue is now resolved as follows: 1. deleted every generated files, except the `.tex` and `.bib` file.2. compiled`.tex` file by `PDFLateX`, 3.  compiled`.tex` file by `biber`, 3. compiled`.tex` file by `PDFLateX` again. Please notice that in step 2, first I compiled`.tex` file by `BibTeX`, which did not wrok (error popped up). Then, I did steps 1,2 and 3, after deleting all generated files and it worked fine.

Comment: @imnothere Do you want to type up a quick answer here, so the question can be marked as resolved?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overleaf uses `latexmk`, which automatically executes `bibtex` or `biber`: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F

If you're not using `latexmk`, you will need to run `bibtex` or `biber` separately in TeXworks/TeXstudio/etc, and then run `pdflatex` again; see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147521 or [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751)