The references are not displayed in TexWorks
I installed TexWorks on Ubuntu 20.4 with all necessary packages. But the references in the file are not displayed and the section \bibliography{References} are not displayed, too. There are many warnings like:
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Suzuki2009p1' on page 1 undefined on input line 99.
Can you help me to understand the source of the problem? Thanks!

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Please also include how you compile your document. Do you run bibtex? See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147521/36296

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number

Thanks, this: tex.stackexchange.com/a/147521/36296 –
samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz helps to compile the file with proper references!
