# the biblatex package doesn't work in Texworks

Tags: biblatex

I have been troubled by the `biblatex` package for a few days in TexWorks. I follow the instructions from the internet in many ways,but things don't make sense to me.

This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\begin{document}
It didn't make sense\cite{gbms}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and this is my `reference.bib`

```
 % This file was created with JabRef 2.10.
% Encoding: GBK


@Article{gbms,
  Title                    = {{Generalized Born Model Based on a Surface Integral Formulation}},
  Author                   = {Avijit Ghosh, Chaya Sendrovic Rapp, and Richard A. Friesner},
  Journal                  = {J.Phys.Chem.B},
  Year                     = {1998},
  Pages                    = {10893-10990},
  Volume                   = {102}
}
```

First I use the pdfLaTeX, things work well and give me the pdf without giving the bibliography

Then I use the biber command the console give me this:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.2
INFO - Logfile is 'parameters.tex.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find control file 'parameters.tex.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

I don't know why it happen?

I also tried the `backend=bibtex`, the program seems to interrupt and give that `! Undefined control sequence.` So, anyone knows this kind of problem?

Comment: you always have to run `parser filename_without_extension`. I guess you're running `biber parameters.tex` which should be `biber parameters`

Comment: I guess musicman is right there, please refer to [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) on how to properly set up your editor with Biber.

Comment: Things work well now, I should use the `$basename` but how to solve the situation 'backend=bibtex' ?

Comment: when you're working with biblatex I recommend use `backend=biber` instead

Comment: When you order `backend=biber` you cannot use BibTeX. Since LaTeX writes some information to auxiliary files you can even get errors when trying to run BibTeX even after switching to `backend=bibtex` (same goes for the other way), you can solve that problem by deleting the temporary `.aux`, `.bcf` and `.bbl` files before compiling. But as musicman says, it is better to use Biber.

Comment: The input of the authors is imho wrong. Separate all authors with "and" `{Avijit Ghosh and Chaya Sendrovic Rapp and Richard A. Friesner}`

Comment: If you've set up `biber` in TeXworks, you've probably used `$fullname`, but that should be `$basename` as in [Dummies Guide to Biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63310). `$basename` will give you the filename without extension.

Comment: Are you OK with closing your question as a duplicate of [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)?

Comment: How can I close the question, It's depend on me or you? Sorry, I'm not so familiar with this.

Comment: We can vote to close your question AFAIK you can then agree with this decision and it will not go through the normal review. I'm not sure how you can initiate the process. But if you are OK with closing it as a duplicate I will do so in a few minutes.

Comment: Yes, I'm OK with this.

Comment: It has been done, then.