# Does a !TEX directive exist in TeXStudio for the bibliography command?

Tags: texstudio

I'm using TeXStudio (2.6.2) for all my tex documents. For my thesis I'm using biblatex, but for papers I usally use bibtex. Therefor I always have to change the configuration of TeXStudio when I'm switching to another document. Is there a `!TEX` like directive for TeXStudio so I can configure it on a per document base? I've seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38348/in-texshop-is-there-a-directive-to-select-biber-or-bibtex-on-a-per-document-bas) that TeXShop supports `!BIB program = ...`. I tried that in TeXStudio, but unfortunately it does not work. I also haven't found any indication in the manual that there is something like that. So my question is: Is there any kind of such a directive for TeXStudio or some other easy work around?

Comment: Related: [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101).

Comment: There are many `make`-like options, such as [`latexmk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) and [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara) (which I've yet to try, but seems dead simple to use).  Can TeXStudio be configured to use them?  Or even a simple `Makefile` is pretty simple to create...

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this is directly possible in TeXstudio  `arara` is a good alternative though. Instructions for setting up TeXstudio for `arara` is found in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118899/586.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I guess you are right, maybe I will take a look on arara. On the other hand it is not too much trouble to switch the bib program. Anyway, if you convert your comment to an answer I will accept it.

Comment: BTW, I created a feature request: http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/662/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `% !TeX TXS-program:bibliography = txs:///biber`. This is a general syntax. TXS understands a number of commands (each starting with `txs:///`). You will find the names when hovering over the command names in the options pages Command and Build. The above means that a call to `txs:///bibliography` (actually that's called when you click the Bibliography menu item) should be resolved to txs:///biber (which in turn resolves to the exact biber call).

Future releases (2.7.x) will also support `% !BIB program = biber` to remain fully compatible with the TeXShop syntax.

Comment: It should be `% !TeX TXS-program:bibliography = txs:///biber` as you described in the feature request. And that works like a charm! Thanks for the quick response.