# How to use Bibulous with TeXShop?

Tags: bibliographies, texshop, bibulous

I'm using TeXShop 3.59 for Mac OS X. If I truly want to customize my citations and/or bibliography, (I think) I want to use [Bibulous](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/).

At any rate, how can I get Bibulous working with TeXShop? I assume I'd need to create a brand new TeXShop Engine for it, but have little/no familiarity with doing that.

Comment: Have you read [Getting started in the bibulous wiki](https://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/getting_started.html)? TeXshop isn't mentioned explicitly but maybe that is enough for you. You can also refer to [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) and [In TeXShop, is there a directive to select biber or BibTeX on a per-document basis?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38348/35864) I have removed the `biblatex` tag, as this question is not about `biblatex`.