# Why might \sin and \cos be italicized in the output?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, unicode-math, italic

#### Introduction

I know that `\sin` and `\cos` are supposed to produce non-italicized (operator) output when in math mode.

Oddly, these macros are producing *italicized output*, as if I had typed `sin` or `cos`---that is, *without* the backslash.

#### My Question

The `unicode-math` package seems to be at fault here. What's going on, and why would it override the trig commands?

#### Minimum Working Example (MWE)

I've got a rather large document, so my MWE includes a few packages that may seem unusual for this MWE. I've stripped it down quite a bit to get what is given below.

Here's the preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,notitlepage,final]{report}
%%##$#% !BIB TS-program = biber
% The above line is REQUIRED -- see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38348/in-texshop-is-there-a-directive-to-select-biber-or-bibtex-on-a-per-document-bas

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % better font -- REQUIRED for special unicode characters
\usepackage{unicode-math}  % for \oiint command (also loads fontspec)
\usepackage{amsmath}  % conflicts with \oiint
\usepackage[arrow]{hhtensor}  % for vector and tensor notation
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Allows me to include figures


\begin{document}

Here's an equation:
\begin{equation}
    1 = \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: never use fontenc with xetex or luatex, use fontspec instead

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks--how come? (If it matters, I use XeLaTeX.)

Comment: it doesn't work:-) with xetex you should use opentype unicode fonts not 8bit tex encoded fonts like T1 encoding (otherwise hyphenation will be wrong)

Answer (score 12):

`unicode-math` should be loaded after all font-packages (well, packages, that load fonts as well, like `amsmath` etc.) are loaded, to provide the corresponding changes.

The `unicode-math` package states (see section 3 *Getting started*):

> Load unicode-math as a regular LATEX package. It should be loaded
>   after any other maths or font-related package in case it needs to
>   overwrite their definitions

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,notitlepage,final]{report}
%%##$#% !BIB TS-program = biber
% The above line is REQUIRED -- see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38348/in-texshop-is-there-a-directive-to-select-biber-or-bibtex-on-a-per-document-bas


\usepackage{amsmath}  % conflicts with \oiint
\usepackage[arrow]{hhtensor}  % for vector and tensor notation
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Allows me to include figures
\usepackage{unicode-math}  % for \oiint command (also loads fontspec)

\begin{document}
Here's an equation:
\begin{equation}
    1 = \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Loading `fontenc` and `lmodern` is completely useless in this context

Comment: @egreg: Yes, but it was in the OP's example already. I just forgot to remove them

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for pointing that out. Why is that?

Comment: @jvriesem `fontenc` is pretty useless with `fontspec` (that's loaded by `unicode-math`); the font choices made by `lmodern` are overridden by `fontspec`.